# why hashmap sums up integer values

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm studying `HashMap` from an Internet example, and I cannot understand why `put()` sums up integer values instead of replacing them? I've tried with a strings, and it does replace, as it should be.

Javadoc says:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. 
>   If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

However:

```
public class testMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Dog, Integer> myH = new HashMap<>();
        Dog d1 = new Dog("white");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("green");
        Dog d3 = new Dog("purple");
        Dog d4 = new Dog("white");
        Dog d5 = new Dog("green");
        Dog d6 = new Dog("white");
        Dog d7 = new Dog("white");

        myH.put(d1, 10);
        myH.put(d2, 20);
        myH.put(d3, 30);
        myH.put(d4, 14);
        myH.put(d5, 15);
        myH.put(d6, 60);
        myH.put(d7, 10);

        System.out.println(myH.size());

        for (Entry<Dog,Integer> line : myH.entrySet() ) {
            System.out.println(line.getKey().toString()+" - "+line.getValue());
        }
    }

}

class Dog {
    String color;

    Dog(String c){
        color = c;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return color + " dog" ;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((Dog) o).color == this.color;

    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return color.length();
    }

}
```

**I withdraw the question. It works perfectly  as  javadoc says, i just did  not  put enough attention to result. ALSO, post can be erased, cause its does not ask any valuable info.**

Comment: This is not very clear. What do you expect? What did you get?

Comment: hashcode implementation seems wrong.

Comment: Why do you think that `put()` sums up integer values?

Comment: @Ved What do you think is wrong with `hashCode()`? If anything, it's the `equals()` method that shouldn't work (but does because of interning)

Comment: Your `hashCode` is just the colour's length - they will all have the same hash code and your `HashMap` is going to behave incorrectly.

Comment: see @EvanKnowles's comment.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I thought that that just means that the map is going to have bad performance due to collisions. The map should still work.

Comment: And @Ved that doesn't make for an incorrect `hashCode()`, just a bad one...

Comment: No, it does not add up, it actually replaces. The output is as it is supposed be. `green dog - 15
white dog - 10
purple dog - 30`. Just to remind, even though, your `equals` function is wrong, and it should be as @Deepak-tiwari explained, your code still work. That is why you directly passed string literals to your constructor. In that case only one object for the same string literals is created and actually all `white`s are the same object. But if you had constructors like `Dog dog = new Dog(new String("white"));` , you would have multiple instances of `white` in your map.

Comment: "ALSO, post can be erased, cause its does not ask any valuable info." You ought to be able to delete your own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String equality check always use equals(). **Btw in this case `==` is OK.**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return ((Dog) o).color.equals(this.color);

}
```

Btw it's showing

```
3
green dog - 15
white dog - 10
purple dog - 30
```

Comment: Thanks, i just overlooked result. Too early morning. Thanks for equals,  i havent noticed this as well.